# Добавление класса через цикл в Angular

Tags: javascript, angular2, frontend

Html:

```
<div class="col-4" id="categories">
        <ul #list>
          <li *ngFor="let category of categories" [ngClass]="{'active': active}">
            {{category.name}}
          </li>
        </ul>
```

На чистом JS необходимая мне функция выглядела бы вот так:

```
    var i=0;
    while(i<list.childElementCount){
      setTimeout(function(){
        if(i == 0){
          list.children[childElementCount-1].classList.remove("active");
        } else {
          list.children[i-1].classList.remove("active");
        }
        list.children[i].classList.add("active");
        i++;
      }, 5000)
```

Как реализовать такое на Angular?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте переменную индекса

```
<div class="col-4" id="categories">
    <ul #list>
      <li *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index;" [ngClass]="i == 0?'active': ''">
        {{category.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

тут мне еще посоветовали использовать другой синтаксис, который можно использовать если у вас несколько условий.

```
<li *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index;" [ngClass]="{'active': i == 0}">
```

Для более ясного ознакомления лучше всего обращаться к первоисточнику [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass).

Comment: Я бы скорректировал: ```[ngClass]="{'active': i == 0}" ```. Так всё таки правильней.

Comment: @SergeyRogachev Есть несколько вариантов, и они описаны в документации.